# Creating json from generic strings

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to do something really simple (at least, should be IMO): create a function that receives a string containing some json and turns that into a Gson object. I've created the following function in my class:

```kotlin
class EasyJson(val url: String, private val responseDataClass: Class<*>) {
    var text: String
    var json: Gson

    init {
        text = getJsonFromUrl(URL(url)) //another function does this and is working fine
        json = stringToJson(text, responseDataClass::class.java) as Gson
    }

    private fun <T> stringToJson(data: String, model: Class<T>): T {
        return Gson().fromJson(data, model)
    }
```

And here is the calling class:

```kotlin
class CallingClass() {
    val url="https://api"
    init {
        test()
    }

    data class ApiResponse(
        val count: Number,
        val next: Number?,
        val previous: Number?
    )
    private fun test(){
        val json = EasyJson(url, ApiResponse::class.java)
    }

}
```

However, when I do this I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

How can I use a generic data class as a parameter for Gson here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is most likely the following line:

```kotlin
stringToJson(text, responseDataClass::class.java)
```

This will use the class of the class, which is always `Class<Class>`. You should just call your `stringToJson` function with `responseDataClass` (without `::class.java`):

```kotlin
stringToJson(text, responseDataClass)
```

Additionally it looks like you treat the `stringToJson` result incorrectly. The result is an instance of `T` (actually `T?` because `Gson.fromJson` can return `null`). However, you are casting it to `Gson`.

The correct code would probably look like this:

```kotlin
class EasyJson<T>(val url: String, private val responseDataClass: Class<T>) {
    var text: String
    var json: T?

    init {
        text = getJsonFromUrl(URL(url)) //another function does this and is working fine
        json = stringToJson(text, responseDataClass)
    }

    private fun <T> stringToJson(data: String, model: Class<T>): T? {
        return Gson().fromJson(data, model)
    }
}
```

(Though unless your code contains more logic in `EasyJson`, it might make more sense to move this JSON fetching and parsing to a function instead of having a dedicated class for this.)